# splitChunks-> cacheGroups css compilation silently fail to execute code in output ( provided demo-repository )

Tags: webpack, commonschunkplugin, mini-css-extract-plugin

I've build a sample minimal-demo repository :  https://github.com/fvigotti/webpack-errordemo

the problem is that when I add this (

```
styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
         minSize:0, minChunks: 1, reuseExistingChunk: true, enforce: true
        },
```

into cacheGroups , no errors gets logged during compilation, the output html is generated with imports ( except for css ) and neither css and javascript works anymore in the compiled output..

I've used the code from the official readme page... is this a problem of mine ? maybe this library could be improved to be more  verbose in error logging ?

Thank you,
Francesco

also I've opened a bug in `mini-css-extract-plugin` https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/180
But i'm not 100% sure this is a  bug of this plugin or a misconfiguration.. (it's a very simple example and I'm following the guide )

if someone show that's not a bug of this plugin I'll close the issue

Answer (score 0):

closing this issue, found the problem, the style chunk was not included in HtmlWebpackPlugin chunks , going also to update the repository referenced in the issue with the fix